# CGRectIntersectsRect at a specific point of the objects?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, xcode6

Like in a Mario game where if you jump and land on **top** of a monster, the monster gets knocked out.

I'm using CGRectIntersectsRect between the two objects (player and monster); however, the monster will get knocked out from any direction.

How do I intersect two objects at **specific points** of the objects?

I actually created separate blank objects in each direction for this to work. Is there a more efficient solution?

Comment: You can use sprite kit's built-in contact detection feature

Comment: I looked up the spritekit guide, and it had the information I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `CGRectIntersectsRect` you can use `CGRectIntersection` to get a new `CGRect` of the area of intersection.  If the player hit from the side, then this rectangle will be taller than it is wide.  If the player hit from the top the rectangle will be wider than it is tall, but you will need to check for top vs. bottom maybe.  In that case, you can compare the Y values of the enemy rectangle with the intersection.  If the player hit from the top, the Y values of the intersection and the enemy rectangle will be equal.  Otherwise, the player hit from the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, IntersectFrom) {
    IntersectFromNotIntersect,
    IntersectFromTop,
    IntersectFromBottom,
    IntersectFromLeft,
    IntersectFromRight
};

IntersectFrom CGRectGetIntersectFrom(CGRect rectPlayer, CGRect rectMonster) {
    CGRect rectIntersect = CGRectIntersection(rectPlayer, rectMonster);
    if(!CGRectIsNull(rectIntersect)) {

        if(CGRectGetWidth(rectIntersect) < CGRectGetHeight(rectIntersect)) {
            // LEFT or RIGHT
            if(CGRectGetMinX(rectIntersect) == CGRectGetMinX(rectMonster)) {
                return IntersectFromLeft;
            }
            else {
                return IntersectFromRight;
            }
        }
        else {
            // TOP or BOTTOM
            if(CGRectGetMinY(rectIntersect) == CGRectGetMinY(rectMonster)) {
                return IntersectFromBottom;
            }
            else {
                return IntersectFromTop;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        return IntersectFromNotIntersect;
    }
}
```